# Cech cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms

In  the construction of Cech cohomology on the category of open(X) via direct system of groups, we consider two group elements that agree on their restriction on a refinement (open set) to be equivalent. This does not make intuitive sense to me. Take the group elements to be elements of the cohomology of differential  forms. Two elements here can agree on an open set but still be different elements. Am I missing something?

(see pp 112 of Bott and Tu for an example of such a case 
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf)

In the above reference, you will see that we start with with the disjoint union of the groups. Then, we declare as equivalent two elements in the disjoint union $g$ in $G_a$ and $h$ in $G_b$ if  $f^a_c(g)=f^b_c(h)$  in $G_c$ with $c$ less than both $a$ and $b$. In terms of "forms" (well in cohomology the forms are themselves equivalent classes of closed forms via exact forms) , this means if two forms agree on an open set, we declare them as equivalent. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what is your problem. The cohomology depends on a fixen open cover. But if a cover is a subcover of another cover, it is likely to bring more informations : passing through the limits we get the Cech cohomology.
"Two elements here can agree on an open set but still be different elements." I don't understand the meaning of your interrogation. No one claimed that taking a subcover will induce isomorphism in cohomology ! We just have map $H(F,U) \to H(F,V)$ if $U > V$. And you take the direct limit of such systems.

Comment: @N.H. please see my edited question, please take a look at pp 112 of the link; the map you mention in cohomology is the "restriction"  hence my question.

Comment: @ N.H aha is it because here by "homomorphism" they mean not just from one open set to the other but for *every* open set in the cover? I am not used to functorial language. So in this case they mean two forms agree in their restriction on every elements of $G_c$?

Comment: If we have a subcover $V$ of $U$, you get for free a map $H(F,U) \to H(F,V)$ simply by sending a cocyle to its various restrictions and check that coboundaries are send to coboundaries. As I said this map is usually not an isomorphism. But cohomology with respect to one fixed cover is not very interesting, what is really interesting is taking the limit because it does not depends anymore from the cover you picked. I hope it is clear. If you need more details, probably it's a good idea to look at $H^1$ of a Riemann surface, this is really well done in Forster and you can do everything by hand.

Comment: And yes they have to agree on every element of $G_c$.